# Output data through jspInit() method

Tags: java, jsp

Hi I'm new at `jsp` and I'm making some exercises, the 1st one is to output data through the `jspInit()` method, and I haven't been able to make it work u.u (I know this is too dumb). Everything works fine on my `jsp` page until I write the method like this:

```
<%! 
public void jspInit()
{
    out.println("Inicializando el servlet de bienvenida");
}  %>
```

and the message I get from the server is "out cannot be resolved".

Is there any other way to make this method print some output data?

I'd also like to know the reason why my code doesn't work =(

Comment: What do you think `out` is referring to? Why do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to output to print you can use `System.our.println()`.

```
<%! 
public void jspInit()
{
    System.out.println("Inicializando el servlet de bienvenida");
}  %>
```

Implicit objects are not available inside `jspInit() or jspDestroy()` method.That means implicit objects are available in `_jspService()` method only.The implicit objects are the local varible inside Service Method.So, these are not accessible out side this method.

```
public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

    JspFactory _jspxFactory = null;
    PageContext pageContext = null;
    HttpSession session = null;
    ServletContext application = null;
    ServletConfig config = null;
    JspWriter out = null;
    Object page = this;
    JspWriter _jspx_out = null;

    //other code here
}
```

Comment: Now my code works without error, but the message i want to print with the statement 'System.out.println("Inicializando el servlet de bienvenida");' doesn't appear in my page yet =(

Comment: Yes, System.out.println() will print to console.

Comment: I know, but the purpose of the exercise is to print some output to the browser, now the question is: is it possible to do so through the method jspInit ? or can it be used only to perform other tasks like opening db connections ?